# get a cookie or session from one web application to another web application

Tags: java, jsp, session, cookies

I have two web projects Admin and Dashboard. AdminEAR is being deployed on server which has project Admin and Dashboard.

I am giving a href link in Admin project JSP which will take me to Dashboard index page.

The Admin project URL is

> http://localhost:8080/admindesktop/admin/

and the href will take us to a page with URL

> http://localhost:8080/BMDashboard/index

Admin has an username which I want to fetch in project Dashboard.
If someone logs out of Admin project, I want Dashboard to be logged out as well.

How can I achieve it? Do you guys have any suggestions.

Dashboard uses Spring and Hibernate but Admin does not use it. It is simple web app

Comment: [Cookies](https://techblog.topdesk.com/security/cookie-security/) with the appropriate domain and path.

Comment: @SBylemans, will you please guide me with a practical approach (code) rather than theoretical one?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a cookie with the path explicitly set to "/" and see if you can access it from the other application as well since the context-root won't be in play. Once you have confirmed that you have access to the cookie (should be able to inspect this in the browser as well), you can create a javascript interval function that constantly polls the server for the state of the cookie... if the cookie has been removed (set max time to live to -1) redirect the user to the logout page and invalidate the session. The below code snippet is the standard approach to creating a cookie:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("auth_token",cookieValue);
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setMaxAge(28800);
cookie.setPath("/");
httpResponse.addCookie(cookie);
```

The below code snippet is invalidating the cookie:

```
cookie.setMaxAge(0) // important part to invalidate the cookie;
cookie.setPath("/");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: I am new to session and cookies and  not aware of setting path for the cookie. will you please give me some code example.

Comment: thanks mate. I can now get the cookie in Dashboard App. but i am still confused about the log out functionality. Should I go for Javascript function or a Java function in backend instead of browser ?

Comment: @Ayush You should do the logout with a Java function in the backend. If you make your cookie HttpOnly, you will not be able to access it in JS.

Comment: @Ayush You could also create an interval Javascript function that polls a rest service or a servlet in your backend...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably use Single Sign on, if you have multiple applications that you want to have common login to:

> https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/single-sign-on

If you can't do this, then sharing cookie with a "/" path will be the minimilist approach. Take a look at the following link:-

> http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26138&seqNum=7